# Function scatter_mapbox returns only blank maps. How to solve it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, map-function, plotly-express

I'm trying to use the function "scatter_mapbox" from plotly.express and everything I get back are blank maps. I'm having this issue in Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.9.12. I have tried to generate maps with other functions such as "line_geo" with sucess, but it will be really good for my purposes if i could get this function properly running.

This is a example of a code that runs ok:

```
fig = px.line_geo(lat=[0,15,20,35], lon=[5,10,25,30])
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
fig.update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

This is a example of a code that do not run as intended:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
houses = data[['id','lat','long', 'price']].copy()

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(houses,
                        lat='lat',
                        lon='long',
                        hover_name='id',
                        hover_data=['price'],
                        zoom=3,
                        height=300
                        )

fig.show()
```

I also tried to generate the map only with the database and lat/lon paramaters also without sucess.

The databese in from here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivachandel/kc-house-data

I also enable the use of Open GL and that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been checking your problem and maybe your error is that you are using a function that plot using mapbox. **For that you would need to import the mapbox token**, like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
houses = data[['id','lat','long', 'price']].copy()

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(houses,
                        lat='lat',
                        lon='long',
                        hover_name='id',
                        hover_data=['price'],
                        zoom=3,
                        height=300
                        )

fig.show()
```

[Here](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/) you can find info about how to obtain it.

**By the way, you can plot it without the token using a public USGS imagery map:**

```
data = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
houses = data[['id','lat','long', 'price']]

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(houses,
                        lat='lat',
                        lon='long',
                        hover_name='id',
                        hover_data=['price'],
                        zoom=3,
                        height=300
                        )


fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_style="white-bg",
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "below": 'traces',
            "sourcetype": "raster",
            "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
            "source": [
                "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
            ]
        }
      ])
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You can also use open-street-maps easily just update the figure `fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")`